# Limitations of MySQL connections

Tags: php, mysql

I have some unanswered questions regarding the Mysql database and would like to have them answered by you if you guys don't mind. The answers will determine my decision in using it and future use of it.

A: Can I have a database with 10 billion tables ?

B: There is maximum limit of 100,000 connection in MySQL, how does Facebook run the whole world if this limit exists? What is the workaround?

C: Is that limit of 100,000 connections per. database or table?

D: What if my script file (in that case I'm using PHP) closes the MySQL connection at the end of the file? Can the limit still be exceeded?

Comment: A. eh? B,C what are you doing so that you care about 100000 connection?  D you **must** close connections, not closing them is bad practice.

Comment: I'm closing them, but what if 100000 connection happens at same time?

Comment: Then hopefully your server has enough memory to handle that many connections along with the other processes that are running.

Comment: what is enough memory ? how to know that

Comment: There are plenty of online calculators. [Here's](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/how-do-you-calculate-mysql-max-connections-variable) how you calculate it.

Comment: @sara Did you already look at a real mysql server on a real webserver? How many connections do you have? Do simple math : Your page is loading in an average time of two seconds 100000 / 2 = 50000 pages per second. 50 page/s = 4.3Gpages / day

Comment: If you're asking these questions, you probably have no idea what your scaling factors are. Build a prototype and test it under simulated load to see how it performs. Additionally, if you're talking about ten *billion* tables you really need to re-think your schema, that's completely nuts. Nobody has that many tables, not even Google, because it's absolutely impossible to manage. I've seen companies get into the high tens and hundreds of millions before radically re-architecting to cut that down by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: @sarahansen If you need to clarify your question you can edit it at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A: Can i have a database with 10 billion tabels ?

No, you cant make those in a lifetime on any real world software. Do you know how many zeroes are there in 10 billion btw? :)

> B: There is maximum limit of 100000 connection in mysql, how does
>   facebook run the whole world if this limit exist. What the workaround?

They have countless number of database servers. Let alone top notch architecture and highly paid engineers.

> C: Is that limit of 100000 connection per. database or tabel?

For your server that limit might be 200 only :) It's per server btw.

> D: What if my script file (in that case i'm using php) close the mysql
>   connection at the end of the file. Can the limit still be exceeded?

Yes, if there are others on it still.

Now let met add something here. By the time you reach 100k legit connections at one time you will already be a multi million dollar setup and will be able to afford people and resources to run and manage your database effectively then it will be their headache to manage that :)

Comment: Even on an 8TB hard drive, 10 billion tables is going to be a squeeze. That's barely 800 bytes per table.

Comment: Maybe they're a sort of "talent scout" and looking for someone wanting to be part of their probject so you'll end up being the master engineer ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- although i am one of the least talented ones out there but if for such requirements somebody paid me a hefty some i'd still have to refuse cause that's just not real world. Its all hypothetical numbers

Comment: 10 billion records, not tabels. Sorry. :)

Comment: Yes 10 billion records many databases have.

Comment: So that would be no problem, right?

Comment: Wrong. It will be one hell of a problem :) But yes its doable

Comment: @sarahansen Ten billion records is a lot, but it's doable. See [Jetpants](https://github.com/tumblr/jetpants) for an example, it's what Tumblr does to manage their infrastructure.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky check your home mailbox; there might be a special offer coming in soon ;-)

Comment: To quote from the link tadman gave: *Jetpants was created by Tumblr to help manage our database infrastructure. It handles automation tasks for our entire database topology, which as of May 2013 consists of over **215 dedicated database servers** and nearly 200 billion total distinct relational rows.*